# React -> constructor's this not equal to componentDidMount this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a rather large React project, in which, no matter which of my components I try it with, the 'this' of its constructor is not equal to the 'this' of, say, the componentDidMount method.

To be sure, that this is usually the case, I made a little test project on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ppwy1pww0q

There it is working correctly, but not in my project.

Before I remove everything from my project to make it resemble the example, does anyone have ever seen something similar before? I am using react 16.2.0, with webpack 3.10, webpack-dev-server and typescript.

Comment: I think this is expected since `this.props` or `this.state` changes

Comment: its hard to tell the problem when we cannot replicate the issue. just to be safe instead of declaring `this.myvariable` in `componentdidmount` you can declare it in `constructor` itself

Comment: Please post the non-working code.

Comment: It's very hard to post the non working code, because I would have to strip down a very large project. And in new project, I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: but can you tell what exactly you want to achieve with `this`

Comment: I want to check references of components. But to my dismay, in my project, they are different, depending on where I first store them.

Comment: You should identify your components by their parent (maybe pass an id prop) not by comparing `this`

Comment: Exactly, it does. Only in my local project, does it not. There is definitely something fishy going on in my local project setup, I just hoped, somebody might have had a similar situation before and could give me a pointer. EDIT: Huh, comment is gone.

Comment: Have you tried getting your reference to `this`in componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount ?

Comment: Yes, I have, no difference. I actually made some progress. It seems, react-hot-loader is doing stuff here. It creates proxies around each component. Maybe that causes the issue. If I remove react-hot-loader completely from my project, things suddenly work.

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually found the issue. I am using react-hot-loader, which in turn uses react-proxy. There is an issue with class method bindings open for this:

https://github.com/gaearon/react-proxy/issues/69